# best Phaedrus edition to start with for beginner

Tags: plato, socrates, rhetoric

I'm interested particularly in Socrates' condemnation of written words and its propensity to create a false and superficial sense of intelligence which seems so prescient in light of how people use the internet to mine info to back up their beliefs.

I am hoping for a recommendation on a good book edition with guides to help me understand what I'm reading.

Comment: Do you mean that you need a good translation in english of the original ancient text?

Answer (score 2):

The Hackett English editions/translations of Plato are reliably good ones, and some of the best presented. Their [edition of *Phaedrus*](http://www.hackettpublishing.com/phaedrus), translated by Nehemas and Woodruff, is no exception. It doesn't offer line-by-line commentary, but contains an introduction, outline,  footnotes, and a couple essays at the end. I think you won't have trouble reading it with those aids.